# How do I solve a key error 412 in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a script to clean some data I have scraped from PubMed, but when I try to run it, it returns a key error 412. I don't know if it has something to do with a change in the API. Here is some of the code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\SOPHIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20828/3897951539.py in <module>
      6     x = 0
      7     for y in range(0, 5583):
----> 8         if i == dfdrop.at[y,'AuthorCount']:
      9             x += 1
     10     x = round(x/5583, 2)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2273             return self.obj.loc[key]
   2274 
-> 2275         return super().__getitem__(key)
   2276 
   2277     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2220 
   2221         key = self._convert_key(key)
-> 2222         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
   2223 
   2224     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _get_value(self, index, col, takeable)
   3577 
   3578         try:
-> 3579             loc = engine.get_loc(index)
   3580             return series._values[loc]
   3581         except AttributeError:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 412
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error is saying is in the block of code below:

```
      6     x = 0
      7     for y in range(0, 5583):
----> 8         if i == dfdrop.at[y,'AuthorCount']:
      9             x += 1
     10     x = round(x/5583, 2)
```

after your loop iterates 412 times on the 413th `y = 412` and the expression in line 8 fails because `412` is an invalid key.

To fix it just change the `range(0, 5583)` to `range(len(dfdrop.index))`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you have an idea to how this could be solved?

Comment: Sure, change change the `range(0, 5583)` to `range(len(dfdrop.index))`

Comment: @SophieRønnstad  I will update my answer so you can mark it complete